# Yeoman webapp deploy, my json file don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, gulp, gulp-watch

I just create my portfolio and add the library particles.js. Everything working locally but when I push (gulp build/deploy) my particles don't show. I check the console and get a 404 error for my particles.json.

[This is my repo](https://github.com/EQuimper/thinkful-portfolio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer, I put the particles.json file inside the root and I've change the src for import it.

```
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function() {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you move `particles.json` to the scripts directory and change the way it's loaded to:

```
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function() {
```

Comment: I try and nothing happen but in my localhost his working.